# Power Query in SSIS - Do not support Html.Table

Tags: ssis, powerbi, powerquery, azure-data-factory

SSIS supports Power Query as a Source, but do not seem to support M code using Html.Table. I'm using only SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT)

M code below=

```
 let Scrapper =

(Page as number) as table =>
let
    Source = Web.BrowserContents("https://www.zerohedge.com/?page=" & Number.ToText(Page)),
    #"Extracted Table From Html" = Html.Table(Source, {{"Title", ".teaser-title:nth-last-child(4)"}, {"Date", ".extras__created:nth-last-child(1)"}, {"Views", ".extras__views:nth-last-child(2)"}}, [RowSelector=".view-content:nth-last-child(2) > DIV.views-row"]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Extracted Table From Html",{{"Title", type text}, {"Date", type datetime}, {"Views", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type",



    Source = {0..1},
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Converted to Table",{{"Column1", "Pages"}}),
    #"Invoked Custom Function" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "Scrapper", each Scrapper([Pages])),
    #"Expanded Scrapper" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Invoked Custom Function", "Scrapper", {"Title", "Date", "Views"}, {"Title", "Date", "Views"})
in
    #"Expanded Scrapper"
```

> Error: 0x0 at Data Flow Task, Power Query Source: The import
>   Html.Table matches no exports. Did you miss a module reference?

I don't see any other solution that wait for Microsoft to support Html.table

[error image in SSDT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6u06.png)

Comment: Sadly, not all power query functions are soported in ssis or power bi service. This is one of them. I couldn't find a way to make it work either

Comment: "There will be a steady roll out of improvements going forward until Ignite in November" so within 3 months we should have I hope the 2 main issues with Power Query 1. Lack of functions and guidance ( think https://dax.guide/ website with compatibility Version) and 2. SSIS package deployment . SQL agent cannot Schedule a package with Power Query as a Source.